# Minizinc: How to use a predicate in an assert statement?

Tags: constraint, constraint-programming, minizinc

Trying to use minizinc builtins to do some basic validation of data inputs but I get a type error `MiniZinc: type error: no function or predicate with this signature found: 'assert(var bool,string)'`
Is this because I'm using a predicate and not a function?

```
include "globals.mzn";
array[1..5] of int: x = 1..5;
constraint assert(increasing(x), "x is not increasing");
```

Comment: Maybe it's just because you are passing two arguments to `assert`. Check [Predicate](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.3.2/en/predicates.html)

Comment: Similar error. i think assert needs the first argument to be an expression that evaluates to a regular bool rather than a var bool. `MiniZinc: type error: no function or predicate with this signature found: `assert(var bool)'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`assert` requires a `bool` in the test part, and don't support `var bool`.

A suggestion is to rewrite the `increasing` constraint to a loop with single asserts with `bool` expressions. For example:

```
include "globals.mzn";
int: n = 5;

array[1..n] of 1..n: x = [5,4,3,1,2];

constraint forall(i in 1..n-1) (
   assert(x[i] <= x[i+1], "x is not increasing")
);

solve satisfy;

output[ "\(x)\n"];
```

This yield the following error:

```
MiniZinc: evaluation error: 
   /home/hakank/g12/me/assert_test.mzn:31:
   in call 'forall'
   in call 'forall'
   in array comprehension expression
   with i = 1
   /home/hakank/g12/me/assert_test.mzn:32:
   in call 'assert'
   in call 'assert'
   Assertion failed: x is not increasing
```

Update: Another way is to put the `forall` inside `assert`, i.e.

```
% ...
constraint
    assert(
       forall(i in 1..n-1) (
           assert(x[i] <= x[i+1], "x is not increasing")
       )
       , "x is not increasing"
     );
```

Comment: Any reason you don’t do the forall inside the assert? Would that also result in var bool?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to answer your question. There are no reason that I prefer `assert` on each line more that I'm used to it. As you might have seen, I added the alternative approach.